# Does the date that appears in the Search Engine Result Page affect the page rank?

Tags: seo, pagerank, search-results

question in the title + how do I change the date appearing in the result page?

Comment: [See previous](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17887/google-search-results-now-shows-last-updated-for-some-results-how-does-it-work/17891#17891) for some notes on the date in results.

Answer (score 3):

No, it does not affect rank. You will find plenty of new and old pages ranking well for just about any search query.

Comment: do you have any source? would be nice thanks